# Using synchronous process asynchronously in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, event-loop, libuv

I've dig recently in under the hood of **NodeJS** and need some clarification about its **Queue** and **Event Loop**.

NodeJS is single threaded, so if I've for example a function: [`findTheMeaningOfLife()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) which is synchronous function and will invoke it as is, it can took a while till I get [`42`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

But how does it will behave if I'll wrap this function in a `Promise`? For example:

```
function findTheMeaningOfLifeAsync(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        try {
            var meaningOfLife = findTheMeaningOfLife();
            resolve(meaningOfLife);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }

    })
}
```

And will invoke it, will it be placed on NodeJS (libuv) queue and invoked in a different thread? If not, how can I make it truly asynchronous?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me clarify something: Node Js is not single-thread, it has **one execution thread** and **several service threads** (the latter are used for I/O operations).

Having said that, the typical behavior of the code you propose would be the following:

1. You call `findTheMeaningOfLifeAsync()` from outside with a `.then()` handler.
2. The called function returns immediately a promise, and the caller function waits for that promise to resolve and to keep on with its execution.
3. While the caller function is waiting, other events keep being processed in the **execution thread**, so the whole event loop does not stall.
4. Once the called function has finished execution, it will return the promise resolution to the caller function.
5. The caller function will now resume its execution with the result from the promise resolution.

Therefore, regarding your main question, making use of promises will somehow monitor the current state and wait for resolution before resuming from the saved point. However, this does not involve the use of multithreading (since in this case I/O operations are not included I assume), but instead **events** are used to provide asynchronous programming. I recommend you to have a look at Node Js events to have a deeper understanding. I provide you with a useful link here:
[NodeJs Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)